# if always set to true when adding isset

Tags: php, arrays, object, if-statement, isset

At first look, this snippet seems to be fine.

```
// my_controller.php
$data['errors'] = (object)$this->session->userdata('errors_registration');
$this->load->view('registration/my_view',$data);

// print_r($data['errors'])
// stdClass Object
// (
//    [domain_err] => 0
//    [wbholder_err] => 0
//    [methodpayment_err] => 0
//    [createaccount_err] => 2
//    [gtc_err] => 0
// )

// my_view.php
if($errors->domain_err == 1) echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE"; // FALSE
```

And when, `$data['errors']` is empty,

```
// print_r($data['errors'])
// stdClass Object
// (
//    [scalar] => 
// )

// my_view.php
if($errors->domain_err == 1) echo "TRUE"; else echo "FALSE";
```

I get this,

> **A PHP Error was encountered** Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$domain_err

To address the notice, I added `isset()`, making my snippet now to `if(isset($errors->domain_err) == 1)`, however, since this change, the condition seems to be always set to true, thus outputting **TRUE**. Is there other way around to get over the notice while maintaining the conditional output I am expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for it always being true, is because you are comparing it now to what the function returns, which is true because $errors->domain_err is set. What you need to do is change the condition to:

if(isset($errors->domain_err) && $errors->domain_err == 1)

isset does not return the value of the variable, just whether it exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

to avoid repeating this pattern

```
if (isset($errors->domain_err) && $errors->domain_err == 1)
```

you can write a function like this

```
function check_value(&$variable) {
  return (isset($variable) ? &$variable : false);
}
if (check_value($errors->domain_err)) { echo "ERROR"; }
else { echo "NO ERROR"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you try to "get over" the error message?  Fix whatever is causing the error.  In this case you are referencing a member that doesn't exist in the object you are using.  In the code you posted I do not see where you instantiated the $errors class nor did you post any code from it.  Go look in whatever class that is and see if you see a member variable named $domain_err defined and make sure it is defined to be publicly available.  Personally I don't like giving member variables public scope as I prefer to provide a get/set type function to set or return the values of them.